# If the equation $2x^2-7x+12=0$ has two roots alpha and beta ,then the value of alpha/beta+beta/alpha is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the equation $2x^2-7x+12 =0$ has two roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ,

then the value of $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ is

note $x=\frac{-7+\sqrt{47}}{4},\frac{-7-\sqrt{47}}{4}$
then 
$$\frac{\frac{-7+\sqrt{47}}{4}}{\frac{-7-\sqrt{47}}{4}}+\frac{\frac{-7-\sqrt{47}}{4}}{\frac{-7+\sqrt{47}}{4}}$$
so 96/2

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I could not understand anything. Please make it clear. Please [read](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I wanted to edit it but it is bit confusing so it is better that you should do it by yourself.

Comment: This equation has no real roots.

Comment: @TonyK does it matter?

Comment: @user157716: No, but it means that the roots can't be $\dfrac{-7\pm\sqrt{47}}{4}$.

Comment: In fact they are $\dfrac{7\pm\sqrt{-47}}{4}$.

Comment: yes. the given roots are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{\alpha\beta}=\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta}$

since $\alpha+\beta=\frac{7}{2}$ and $\alpha\beta=6$, you can compute the value by substituting.

Comment: But i get 1/8 for alpha*beta.see \frac{-7+\sqrt{47}}{4}*\frac{-7-\sqrt{47}}{4}

Comment: tell me @user157716

Comment: if the quadratic equation is ax^2+bx+c = 0, alpha*beta = c/a, in this case, 12/2, so, 6

Comment: I know that.with imaginary roots as alpha and beta we don't get that 6 as answer

Comment: I don't know exactly @user157716

Comment: why not? how did u get 8, can u show ur work?

Comment: ((-7+ sqrt(47))/4)*((-7-sqrt(47))/4) is it right?

Comment: No, the roots are, 7+sqrt(47)i/4 and 7-sqrt(47)i/4, since the roots are complex, u cant just write sqrt(-47) as sqrt(47),'i' should be there to indicate the complex part (i^2 = -1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16744/discussion-between-user157716-and-jyothika).

Comment: sorry @user157716 .I didn't see any input  area to chat for me then How can i chat with you.

Comment: I get it now .Its become 6 now by using sqrt(-47)

Comment: you have to log in. anyway. do u still have problems?

Comment: chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback.sorry its not getting login why?

Comment: mh. finding roots are not necessary to find the answer for the question. Avoid finding roots if u can substitute using alpha+beta and alpha*beta

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your quantity can be rewritten as

$\frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{\alpha \beta}$,

and the numerator and denominator here are both symmetric polynomials in $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

On the other hand, for any polynomial, the coefficients themselves are in fact symmetric polynomials in the roots. By dividing by the leading coefficient (which doesn't change the roots), we may as well assume that a polynomial is monic (which in our case gives us $x^2 - \frac{7}{2} x + 6$).

Now, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of a monic polynomial $x^2 + bx + c$, we must have

$x^2 + b x + c = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = x^2 + (- (\alpha + \beta)) x + \alpha \beta$, and comparing like coefficients gives

$-b = \alpha + \beta$ and $c = \alpha \beta$.

In fact, these elements generate the ring of symmetric polynomials in $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so we can express all such polynomials as polynomial combinations of these. In particular, we find that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = (\alpha + \beta)^2 - 2 \alpha \beta = (-b)^2 - 2 c = b^2 - 2c$. So, for a monic polynomial, the ratio is

$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} + \frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{\alpha \beta} = \frac{b^2 - 2c}{c} = \frac{b^2}{c} - 2$.

Evaluating for $b = -\frac{7}{2}$, $c = 6$ gives the result for your polynomial.